# Strange error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"

Tags: permissions

I've tried for days to figure this out, with countless research hours involved. I've exhausted reviews of other threads on here and on Google with no luck.

```
/wp-admin/update-core.php
```

Currently at Wordpress v3.6.1, and attempting to upgrade (if it would let me).

This file produces the error. I've tried...

- Overwriting the core
- Disabling plugins
- Tweaking values of capabilities columns

Nothing works. I've even tried creating new administrator accounts and I still cannot get around this error.

Here's what my admin capabilities looks like for one of the admin users:

```
wp_capabilities      a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
wp_user_level        10
```

That is what a freshly created admin user looks like.

The issue is not logging in. The issue is that once logged in, I cannot see any upgrade options for Wordpress core or any plugins. It's like the "upgrade" capability has completely vanished for some reason.

This is what shows under "Plugins" in the admin:

[image: Plugins left nav]

This is what I get when manually trying to browse to update the core at `/wp-admin/update-core.php`:

[image: Attempting to update core]

Seriously ready to pull my hair out guys. Never seen this one up close and personal like this. Totally new to me, and I deal almost exclusively with Wordpress.

Comment: Do you have wp_debug enabled? If not, have you tried enabling it and seeing if any errors popup?

Comment: That didn't produce anything helpful. A plugin or two had some "headers already sent" exceptions being thrown, but I've disabled those plugins and the issue persists. Nice idea though!

Comment: Curiously errors in `update-core.php` are differently worded. Had you tried dumping `current_user_can('update_core')` ? Disable plugins / switch to default theme, something might be messing with it.

Comment: Which plugins have you installed? Any plugins related to roles/capabilities?

Comment: @czerspalace Nothing relating to roles or capabilities have been installed. I did install one or two to troubleshoot this issue, but removed them after finding that they didn't help resolve the issue.